# Enable Hibernate on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop

Tags: laptop, asus, hibernate, lts, 22.04

Using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop on my Asus K55VJ-120XD Corei5,8gb Ram,2gb Vram.How can i activate hibernate on my system so that i can use it in place of suspend like in Windows OS ??

Comment: Visit [https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10 "https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10") It could be of so much help.